# How can I automate this function call with a single statement?

Tags: python, performance, function

-There are two data sources with information about cats and dogs (cat_data and dog_data - both are global variables defined in the main outside of this function.

-Goal is to grab the data from "cat_data" and store into "cat_list" or "dog_data" stored into "dog_list" or lastly create both lists and fill it with the right data. These list(s) then need to be called upon and stored in a way it can be used outside of this localized function.

-The single parameter for my function is: "my_selection" - and can be "cat", "dog" or "both" and will determine if I need to create a cat_list, or a dog_list or both lists and then fill each list from the right data.

-Assume the data filling the lists is correct and that each list is correctly created and filled in each if loop. (Yes I know I have to first define it as an empty list and then append by iterating through the data -  this part works great and I wanted to simplify it to ease reading.

-Here is my code:

```
def create_lists (my_selection):

if (my_selection == "cat" or my_selection == "both"):
    cat_list_local = cat_data    # "cat_list_local" is just my localized cat_list variable
    
    if (my_selection == "cat"):
        return(cat_list_local) #if "cat" is selected, they only want a cat_list

if (my_selection == "dog" or my_selection == "both"):
    dog_list_local = dog_data    #"dog_list_local" is just my localized dog_list variable 
    
    if(my_selection == "dog"):
        return(dog_list_local) #if "dog" is selected, they only want a dog_list
    
    else:
        return( cat_list_local, dog_list_local) # if "both" was selected, we have now created and filled both lists and need to return both lists out of the function

# These are my Function calls below and the part where I am struggling:
# This is the best I can think of....where I will have to just run the one statement (line) based on what list(s) I want

dog_list = create_lists("dog")
cat_list = create_lists("cat")
cat_list, dog_list = create_lists("both")
```

However instead of having these three separate function calls, I wanted to have
only one somehow. I was thinking along the lines of a second function that
takes in your selection parameter (cat, dog or both) and then correctly chooses from the three function calls to call "create_lists() and pull the data.

And I was envisioning a program (or function) type solution that I can simply run in my console with the desired selection parameter to create + populate my lists.
One solution that I had (really ugly though) was creating a selection variable and hard-setting it to "cat", "dog" or "both" and then put if-statements around each of the three function calls based on the selection variable. And so anytime I needed to update the data or change the list, I would change the value of the selection variable, and then highlight all of the if-statements and function calls so itcan execute the correct function call.

However there HAS to be a cleaner way to do this. An ideal solution would be to run SOMETHING like a program or function or something that I really don't know what in the console with the selected parameter and the ensuing statements would fire like a function(). I know I can just define the lists to be global but I want to see if there is another way.

Please advise on proper and healthy coding etiquette here.

Comment: It's hard to tell. Can you provide something that we can look at on repl or another site which allows us to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a neat question because it exposes a lot of little quality of life details that you can add.

First of all, you have these code blocks like:

```py
if choice == 'dog' or choice == 'both':
    # do dog stuff

if choice == 'cat' or choice == 'both':
    # do cat stuff
```

which I see as poor-man's enumeration. Consider a `Flag` enum here.

```py
from enum import Flag, auto
class Dataset(Flag):
    CAT = auto()
    DOG = auto()
    BOTH = CAT | DOG

    # the above is sufficient, but consider writing a constructor as well!
    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, s):
        return cls[s.upper()]
```

Now you can take your user input and use it as:

```py
choice = input("Which dataset? ")  # cat, dog, or both
dataset = Dataset.from_str(choice)
```

"Now Adam," I hear you cry, "What functionality does that give me?" Why, it lets you do membership tests of course!

```py
if Dataset.CAT in dataset:
    # do cat things
if Dataset.DOG in dataset:
    # do dog things
```

Wrap that all in a function and you end up with something like:

```py
from enum import Flag, auto
from typing import Mapping


class Dataset(Flag):
    CAT = auto()
    DOG = auto()
    BOTH = CAT | DOG

    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, s):
        return cls[s.upper()]

# the type hinting I use here assumes that the return value is a
# dict of lists of strings, but if that's incorrect, you can either
# correct it or omit the type hinting completely.
def make_lists(dataset: Dataset) -> Dict[List[str]]:
    """Based on a dataset, create a mapping of output"""

    output = {}

    if Dataset.DOG in dataset:
        output['dog'] = dog_data
    if Dataset.CAT in dataset:
        output['cat'] = cat_data

    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pprint import pprint  # to pretty print the output

    # Get user input
    while True:
        choice = input("Which dataset? ")
        try:
            dataset = Dataset.from_str(choice)
        except KeyError:
            print(f"No dataset found named '{choice}'. Valid choices are {', '.join(Dataset.__members__.keys())}")
        else:
            break
    
    pprint(make_lists(dataset))
```

---

And now for fun, excluding the imports and the enum definition, this is the awful one-liner:

```py
pprint({k: vars().get(f"{k}_data") for choice in [input('Which dataset? ')] for k in ['cat', 'dog'] if Dataset.from_str(k) in Dataset.from_str(choice)})
```

Comment: This is definitely more advanced and complex than I anticipated. It will take me a few days to properly master all of these concepts. Thank you for your comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Py_Student there's almost certainly something more fundamental that can be made without having the Deep Knowledge, but it's unclear from your question what exactly you're looking for.